# Do i need to compile .java files in Eclipse to run application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating dynamic web project in Eclipse.

I have the .java files in `src` folder and other files in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Now normally I click .jsp file and click run on server. But do I also need to compile the .java files in above `src` folder or does Eclipse do that automatically for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse should do it automatically.